# Why is my counter breaking when I add a content tag to a tool tip div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on this tooltip step on building out a final view on something, and was wondering that I'm doing wrong. Snippet where it dies when I add the content tag see css comment and the pen is here 
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/q695/pen/yVmaVP):

**Code:**

```js
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  i++
  num.innerHTML = i;
  //alert(i);
}, 300);
```

```css
.tooltip {
  /* breaks counter/shows image
  content:url(https://lh4.ggpht.com/-rsFqlsSeJUY/WB1eA3b3kWI/AAAAAAEd_WM/mCCZbkZP_XA/w50-h50-c/socialfeed.info-you-magazine.jpg);
  */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
#you {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
#num {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div id="you" class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span id="num" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>

<!--
  counter on number
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span id="num" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)). It isn't meant to be used on a normal element, which is why you're experiencing an issue.

You should be using `background-image` to accomplish what you need, which doesn't have the bug of breaking your hover tooltip.

Here it is in action (I also defined the `width` and `height` of the container):

```js
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  i++
  num.innerHTML = i;
  //alert(i);
}, 300);
```

```css
.tooltip {
  background-image: url(https://lh4.ggpht.com/-rsFqlsSeJUY/WB1eA3b3kWI/AAAAAAEd_WM/mCCZbkZP_XA/w50-h50-c/socialfeed.info-you-magazine.jpg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
#you {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
#num {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div id="you" class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span id="num" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` CSS rule does what it sounds like, it replaces the content of an element.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. You can replace `content` with `background-image`, or simply include an `<img/>` tag in place and remove the `content` rule.